# Center path of android vector

Tags: android, xml, svg, vector, android-vectordrawable

This is my image width and height = 125x125 and the viewport is 62x62, my problem is it's not centered, I want some help to center the path.

[Original SVG](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kLasr4BunMfjVj-Iv9eHRUvK1Ss_YgUq)

```
<vector android:height="125dp" android:viewportHeight="62"
    android:viewportWidth="62" android:width="125dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#000000" android:pathData="M12,5.9c1.16,0 2.1,0.94 2.1,2.1s-0.94,2.1 -2.1,2.1S9.9,9.16 9.9,8s0.94,-2.1 2.1,-2.1m0,9c2.97,0 6.1,1.46 6.1,2.1v1.1L5.9,18.1L5.9,17c0,-0.64 3.13,-2.1 6.1,-2.1M12,4C9.79,4 8,5.79 8,8s1.79,4 4,4 4,-1.79 4,-4 -1.79,-4 -4,-4zM12,13c-2.67,0 -8,1.34 -8,4v3h16v-3c0,-2.66 -5.33,-4 -8,-4z"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with coding and online SVG editor's help sins no one helped me. I wish I had illustrator :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="125dp"
    android:height="125dp"
    android:viewportWidth="250"
    android:viewportHeight="250"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M124.5,92.73C130.543,92.73 135.438,97.625 135.438,103.668C135.438,109.707 130.543,114.605 124.5,114.605C118.457,114.605 113.563,109.707 113.563,103.668C113.563,97.625 118.457,92.73 124.5,92.73M124.5,139.605C139.969,139.605 156.27,147.207 156.27,150.543L156.27,156.27L92.73,156.27L92.73,150.543C92.73,147.207 109.031,139.605 124.5,139.605M124.5,82.832C112.988,82.832 103.668,92.156 103.668,103.668C103.668,115.176 112.988,124.5 124.5,124.5C136.012,124.5 145.332,115.176 145.332,103.668C145.332,92.156 136.012,82.832 124.5,82.832ZM124.5,129.707C110.594,129.707 82.832,136.688 82.832,150.543L82.832,166.168L166.168,166.168L166.168,150.543C166.168,136.688 138.406,129.707 124.5,129.707ZM124.5,129.707"/>
</vector>
```